# How to find all references to an object or a class of objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, profiling

I'm hunting a memory leak in my flash web application.

[**Adobe Scout**](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) showed be that objects of *MyClass* steadily increase with time and eat up memory. Unfortunately, the part of the project that uses these objects is full spaghetti. What would help me out a lot, would be a tool that could show all objects that still own references to all objects of some specific class. I believe [**Adobe Scout**](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) is not capable of that.

Anybody know a tool like that?

Thanks

Comment: Visual C++ had a mode where, when your program finishes, it would print out a list of all the remaining objects that hadn't been deleted. Like if there were a lot of Foo objects left over, that might be a pretty good clue.

Comment: I've never used Adobe Scout, but the profiler that came with Flash Builder Professional had a "loitering objects" view that showed you the same thing as you describe. You could then drill down into each one and see what the "GC root" (garbage collection root) was. The GC root was the thing keeping the object in memory. I'd be a little surprised if Adobe Scout lacked this functionality.